# How to interpret this instruction by Opcode Map?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly, avx, machine-code

This instruction

```
f2 0f 10 05 0a 01 00 00
```

on my machine is disassembled as `movsd  0x10a(%rip),%xmm0` . When reading Intel manual about Opcode Map, I think it should confirm to `vmovsd Vx, Hx, Wsd`, with 3 operands, which confusing me. How to interpret this instruction correctly?

Comment: See section A.2.4.4: "Opcode tables A2-A6 include both instructions with a VEX prefix and instructions without a VEX prefix. Many entries
are only made once, but represent both the VEX and non-VEX forms of the instruction. If the VEX prefix is present
all the operands are valid and the mnemonic is usually prefixed with a “v”."

Comment: This is certainly not `vmovsd` as it is not encoded with a VEX prefix.

Comment: but otherwise I cannot find `movsd `instruction in even One or Two Opcode Map table, but only `vmovsd` there,

Comment: That’s exactly what the paragraph I quoted says: it only lists the instruction once, representing both forms.

Comment: @wuxj Most VEX encoded instructions have corresponding legacy instructions with the same encoding sans the VEX prefix.